# How to allow other user to run a specific program as me like sudo, but both of us are not root in Linux

Tags: linux, sudo

In Linux, I am user1 and my friend is user2 and we are in the same group. In my home, I set read and execute permission to one program says `/home/user1/some_program`.  How can I "grant" user2 to run `/home/user1/some_program` from his session but run as my id? We are both not root.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/) or [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You need to set the `setuid` mode on the file. `chmod u+s some_program`. Anyone who runs the program will run it as your id.

Answer (score 0):

setfacl -m u:username:rwx myfolder or  myfile

Comment: This is not a way to answer pls explain more about it so user can understand or you can comment this single line